# Acessar o conteúdo de um iframe via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Eu tenho um documento html com o nome frame.html com o seguinte código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>frame</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="teste">teste</span>
</body>
```

E um outro documento html com o nome index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="frame.html" id="frameq"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

eu pretendo acessar o conteúdo de dentro do iframe a partir de um script no index.html como por exemplo:

```
document.getElementById('teste').style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
```

Answer (score 1):

Cada janela tem seu `document`, então o `document` do iframe é outro. No caso do seu exemplo:

```
var iframe_document = document.getElementById('frameq').contentWindow.document;
```

A partir desse document você consegue fazer a alteração de estilo – mas apenas se os dois documentos forem do mesmo domínio, caso contrário há restrições de segurança.

```
iframe_document.getElementById('teste').style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
```